# I want to use ASPCOMPAT=true as an attribute of @Page directive

Tags: 2007, asp.net, development

I get the following error on SharePoint pages: ***aspcompat not allowed on this page*** when I try to use it. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

i think this question was already answered on Stackoverflow:
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633361/using-aspcompat-in-a-sharepoint-web-part-page) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627756/adding-web-page-to-blank-sharepoint-site-definition).
Does that help you along?

What is the reason for you setting ASPCOMPAT? are you using single threaded COM components in your code?

hth
Anders